# Ruby/Rails How to parse datetime from russian string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-i18n

I need to parse date\time from string in russian. 
Example: `14:24, 19 мая 2019`.

Comment: There's probably a gem around somewhere to assist. but in this case you could also consider pulling the various parts through Regex and create a hash based lookup to translate the russian month into a month number.

Comment: https://github.com/yaroslav/russian has `strftime`, maybe also `strptime`? (Sorry, I don't speak russian)

Comment: @Felix I tried, it doesn't work unfortunately

Comment: I think you will have to parse by position and do a hash lookup of months.

Comment: @MarlinPierce hardcode, but I think I'll do it like that. But I hope mb someone know better solution

Answer (score 3):

<s>I'd say `Time.parse("14:24, 19 мая 2019")` should work for you ;)</s>

(*In case if you're using rails*)

Yep, it cannot parse not English names of the months, so it should be used like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580238/how-do-i-parse-non-english-dates-with-datetime-strptime-in-ruby):

```
RUSSIAN_MONTH_NAMES_SUBSTITUTION = { 'мая' => 'may', 'июня' => 'june' }

def russian_to_english_date(date_string)
  date_string.gsub(/мая|июня/, RUSSIAN_MONTH_NAMES_SUBSTITUTION)
end

Time.strptime(russian_to_english_date("14:24, 19 июня 2019"), "%H:%M, %d %B %Y")
# or
Time.parse(russian_to_english_date("14:24, 19 июня 2019"))
```

Comment: This will only work when used in the month of May (just because `мая` happens to mean May). In all other months of the year you will get `2019-[current month]-19` because `Time.parse` is not translating anything from one language to another

Comment: Looks like it always place a current month. Tested and unfortunately doesn't work

Comment: It's really parse only English months and using current time to substitute missing part of the date =/ Update the answer to handle it ;)